# Installing codeigniter on subdomain but it is giving 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have installed the codeigniter on subdomain like http://abc.domain.com.
I have modified my htaccess file but it is giving 500 internal error. Please 
tell me required changes to be done in htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*`?

Comment: `RewriteBase` should end with slash.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `RewriteBase` to `/` only and add `base_url` to your config file like,

```
# in htaccess change the RewriteBase
RewriteBase /
```

in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://abc.domain.com/';
```

Also make sure that your htaccess file should be in your `abc` folder, not on the root `www`

Comment: Remove the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*` and check

Comment: Not working. And error log is also not showing any error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I hope you have configured your virtual host properly.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc/or/whatever/
</VirtualHost>
```

And your `Directory` directive

```
<Directory /var/www/html/abc/or/whatever/>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Then place this in the `/var/www/html/abc/or/whatever/.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This should work in most cases. And don't forget to restart apache!